# How to use selectbox of a form for its progress bar in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, progress-bar

When i use the select box in progress bar in jQuery with change event then the width of the progress bar is increased but i need the progress bar increased only once . but it changes all the time when i change the select option.

```
jQuery('#category').on('change', function () {
    var pre_value = parseInt(jQuery('.progress-bar').attr('value'));
    if(jQuery(this).val() != ''){
        jQuery('.progress-bar').val(pre_value + 20);
    } else {
        jQuery('.progress-bar').val(pre_value - 20);
    }
});
```

The output is it increases the width of the progress bar every time when i change the option.